# hive installation on single node cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed hadoop(1.0.3)single node cluster and have tried to install hive(0.13.0)over it. The problem is that everytime i start hive,it creates new tables. No history log is preserved.I am getting this error as well:

```
    WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect. Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
```

I am only able to create table and no other sql command is working.Is there any problem with the hive-site.xml? Because there are way too many config variables in the file and i don't know what to do?

Comment: Please, consider using Hadoop distribution from Cloudera, MapR or Hortonworks. They automates installation and configuration of Hadoop, Hive and many other components from Hadoop ecosystems. It will be much easier for you to install Hive from such distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The error fixed by edit the hive-site.xml
replace hive.metastore.ds.retry width /hive.hmshandler.retry

vim /usr/local/Cellar/hive/0.13.1/libexec/conf/hive-site.xml
:%s/hive.metastore.ds.retry/hive.hmshandler.retry/g
:wq